# Tachometer frequency problem

Tags: motor, npn, speed, tachometer

I have an NPN tachometer sensor. I want to measure the rotation speed of a three phase motor, but the output frequency of the tachometer changes. For example, if the actual value of the motor frequency is 15.2 Hz, the output frequency of the tachometer is between 14.8 Hz and 16 Hz.

I have seen the sensor output on the oscilloscope, the frequency of the pulses is different for different rotation speeds.

The sensor output has a 1K pull-up resistor.

I tested with another motor in another environment. The sensor output is very accurate on the other motor.

Where is the problem?

Comment: what sensor, where located? what interface signal measurements? (poor motor location or bad design).   The time interval changes should not affect the frequency

Comment: Sensor type and model: Diffuse mode sensor glv18-8-200
The sensor is placed in front of the motor shaft and a white label is affixed to the shaft
The output of the sensor is NPN. What do you mean by "poor motor location"?

Comment: You’re lucky to get anything more than a few mV without a pulldown R.

Comment: NOOOOOOO!!
GLV18-8-200 /25/102/115 is NPN 
GLV18-8-200 /115/120      is PNP

Comment: better correct the info in your question

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be in your first sentence.

"I have an NPN tachometer sensor"

The data sheet,

https://files.pepperl-fuchs.com/webcat/navi/productInfo/pds/188574_eng.pdf?v=20210813105651

says it uses PNP outputs. Try pulling the outputs down (to ground) rather than up.

Comment: NOOOOOOO!!
GLV18-8-200 /25/102/115 is NPN 
GLV18-8-200 /115/120      is PNP

Comment: @macrobert - Sorry, then. But you did not give sufficient detail about your sensor. A word of caution - it's always a good idea to provide a direct link to the data sheet of any part you're asking for help with. It prevents this sort of confusion.